# IpTables: rule to allowing outgoing traffic

Tags: iptables, rules

I need rule to allowing outgoing traffic from intranet addresses 192.168.X.X to foreign addresses 123.123.123.0-63 and by using tcp Protocol.

Sorry for bad english

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to Google the answer? We're not here to do the work for you

Comment: yeah, I did but im not familiar with this and couldnt find anything useful. It may have been because my english isnt best about this kind of stuff and I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Try YouTube, look at videos on how to use iptables, this site is used for last resorts if you have tried everything.

Comment: At least add more info on the question, what OS you are running, what have you tried (in your case, at least what you googled).

Comment: And your question is a bit unclear, i obviously you speak a different language, use a translator to translate to English.

Comment: Im using ubuntu and i had to do several things, i got most of it form:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo
this is my last task and because of my bad english (i think) I havent found anything that could help me solve it.
about english. Im using translator to translate computer stuff to english but it doesnt give good results

Comment: Ill help you but i sense lies.

Comment: What is the source ip and or destination address and what port number?

Comment: I was given those tasks and i translated it exactly as I was given.
i had to allow outgoing traffic
192.168.X.X - from those address.  123.123.123.0-63 - to those addresses.
there wasnt anything about ports in this task but previouse task was to block all incoming traffic except port 25 and 80 but i dont think those are related

Comment: Please write next rules for iptables:

     # How to close all incoming traffic except from port 25 and 80

     # how to allow outgoing traffic from intranet addresses 192.168.X.X to foreign addresses 123.123.123.0-63 and by using tcp Protocol.

Thats what I was asked.

Comment: I'll answer it later, OK at work right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.xxx.xxx -d 123.123.123.123/26 -j ACCEPT` - Here, replace the `xxx.xxx` with the actual address.
Try this one for the first question.

**Explanation:**

`/sbin/iptables` - This is the dir of IPTables, you can also just use `iptables ...` and it should work just fine.

`-A OUTPUT` - This will Append the following rule to the `OUTPUT` chain.

`-p tcp` - This specifies the protocol of the packets being handled.

`-s 192.168.xxx.xxx` - This specifies the source IP Address that you want to handle outgoing packets from.

`-d 123.123.123.123/26` - This specifies the destination in which the source ip packets are headed. The one you posted `123.123.123.0-63`, is a 64 subnet, so you will be using a /26 to specify that subnet.

`-j ACCEPT` - Simply tells the firewall to accept these packets from going through.

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

For the next questions, by default, your firewall (iptables) allows all incoming traffic unless you change that. (just FYI)

Allow port 25: `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT`

Allow port 80: `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

Deny all other traffic: `iptables -A INPUT -j DROP`

Be sure to not just copy and paste my answers, study and practice IPTables rules.
http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html